# Автообновление textBox

Tags: c#, textbox, scrollbar

Как можно реализовать автообновление textbox, когда прокручиваешь ScrollBar по сторонам? (без нажатья на кнопку).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: textbox зависит от позиции scrollbar?

Comment: да, в данном случае в textbox выводиться число от значения scrollbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте событие Scroll к ScrollBarу и в нём напишите:

```
private void hScrollBar1_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = e.NewValue.ToString();
}
```